# Output to more than 26 columns in xlsxwriter with python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have a code which generates a list of arbitrary length and outputs it to an excel spreadsheet. It then totals each of the columns with the following code:

```
for i in range(years):
    average = "=AVERAGE("
    average += chr(65+i)
    average += "1:"
    average += chr(65+i)
    average += str(x)
    average += ")"
    worksheet.write(x, i, average)
```

In theory this outputs "=AVERAGE(A1:Ax)" where x is the bottom row of the spreadsheet. I just want to be able to deal with widths greater than 26 i.e. if years is greater than 26 then instead of chr(65+i), the code can say "=AVERAGE(AA1:AAx)" for example.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using csv instead of xlsx? It's much easier to write a row of arbitrary length. And you can use the file with Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a defined method to calculate *ColumnLetter* from column number with no need for Excel's `Char()` conversion:

```
def ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber):
    s = ''
    alpha = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    n = int(ColumnNumber)

    while n > 0: 
        c = ((n - 1) % 26)
        s = alpha[c] + s
        n = (n - c) // 26

    return s

for i in range(years):
    average = "=AVERAGE("
    average += ColumnLetter(i)
    average += "1:"
    average += ColumnLetter(i)
    average += str(x)
    average += ")"
    worksheet.write(x, i, average)
```

Comment: Worked first time. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using XlsxWriter then you can also use the functions it provides to convert `(row, col)` values to strings:

```
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_range

cell = xl_rowcol_to_cell(0, 26)
cell_range = xl_range(0, 26, 66, 26)
formula = '=AVERAGE({})'.format(cell_range)

print(cell)        # AA1
print(cell_range)  # AA1:AA67
print(formula)     # =AVERAGE(AA1:AA67)
```

See the [Working with Cell Notation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html) section of the XlsxWriter docs for more details.

Comment: It's nice to hear from the module author :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you can you should avoid using xlsx files, which are quite annoying to deal with.

Secondly, have you considered calculating your average from within python, and then writing it in the excel file?

If that's still not possible, here is my solution (the thing is actually to convert your column number into a base 26 number, and then associate each digit with the corresponding alphanumeric character)

```
def col_to_char(column): 
    """convert from column number to column name""" 

    if column == 0: return 'A' 
    name=''

    while column!=0: 
        name += ( chr(65 + column % 26) )
        column = column // 26
    return name
```

/!\ BEWARE the columns numbers are here in a pythonic way, i.e. with the first being 0, and not in an "excelic" (?) one, which would be the first being 1

Your code would then be :

```
for i in range(years):
    column_name=col_to_char(i)
    average = "=AVERAGE(" +column_name +"1:" +column_name +str(x) +")"
    worksheet.write(x, i, average)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the alphabetic style of references, it is simpler to use (row,column) style as described here:  https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html